# Magnific Popup onload calling a url

Tags: magnific-popup

I have an static HTML page I want to pop up using Magnific Popup when the page loads. In the examples on the site he only shows clicking a link that has the url of the page. I don't want a link but just page load. How do I get the url to be called without a link? I have the onload figured out

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $.magnificPopup.open({
        type: 'ajax',
    showCloseBtn: true

    }, 0);
});
```

So for example I want test.html to show up in the popup onload. Not sure how this is done.

Comment: Do you want the popup to open immediately after the page is loaded, without user-interaction? Is that your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the magnific popup with a DOM Element created by jQuery and then click it. For example:

```
$(function() {
    $('<a href="test.html">').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax'
    }).click();
});
```

If you need the link appear in the page, then just use appendTo function after click.